# Remove Description from SWT section

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a class extending from SectionPart.

```
public class MyData extends SectionPart{

}
```

In in the initialize method I am creating a section.

```
public class MyData extends SectionPart{
    public void initialize(){
        Section section = this.getSection();
        section.setText("List Items");
        ....
    }
}
```

When I see in the UI under the section I can see there is no description provided but still cursor is blinking there. To remove that I added following code in my initialize method.

```
public class MyData extends SectionPart{
    public void initialize(){
        Section section = this.getSection();
        section.setText("List Items");
        section.getDescriptionControl.setLayout(new GridData());
        section.getDescriptionControl.setVisible(false);
        ((GridData)section.getDescriptionControl().getLayoutData()).exclude = true;
        section.getDescriptionControl().getParent().layout(true);
    }
}
```

Now the description control is invisible but I am not able to remove it from layout. Please help me.

Comment: Please post a specific question. Maybe add a screenshot for better understanding as well.

Comment: @Baz: I want to remove description control from section. Let me know if you know any other details. The main problem is when I inherit from SectionPart one section is created by default which you can get using this.getSection() method of SectionPart. I want to remove Description Control out from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description control will not be added if you do not use the `Section#DESCRIPTION` style flag when creating your section part. If you are seeing the description control then you must be setting this flag in the styles sent to the section's constructor